How suppress or mute EF Core database command on Azure Function
I have these host.json settings trying to suppress the EF Core command picks up by the logs and Application Insights but it doesn't work (the commands still shows up).
Here's the host.json:
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": false,
                "excludedTypes": "Exception",
                "includedTypes": "Trace"
            }
        },
        "logLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning",
            "Function": "Information",
            "Host.Results": "Information",
            "Host.Aggregator": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning"
        }
    }
}

I've tried to add this too.
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning"

This is what I get when I run it:

How do I mute the commands and queries generated by EF Core?

When using .NET you set this in your appsettings.json to error it should only show errors. Or you fully delete this line.
 "Logging": {
     "LogLevel": {
         "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Error"
     }
 }


I've tried your suggestion. However, it doesn't work.

Do you have an appsettings.json? You have to put it there, when using .NET.

One way to mute the EF commands is adding filters in code. This is from my Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
     ...

    }).ConfigureLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogLevel.Warning);
    })
    .Build();

